# How to execute a BeanShell PostProcessor after all samples end on Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

My goal is make a beautiful report about my test plan. I'm using about 50 threads and infinite loop so I want get the responses content and make the report. The problem is that the PostProcessor execute every sample request end so I can't put it all together on the same context to use all data and if I use the data every sample ends the results becomes a big mess. I don't found the solution on the web and I'm newbie with Jmeter. So, there are a way to wait all threads ends and get all responses data on 1x time ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all don't use Beanshell, since [JMeter 3.1 you should switch to JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. If you need to collect response data the best option is writing it into a file using i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) and if any post-processing is needed you can perform this using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) in the [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group)